# Syntax error near unexpected token `if' in shell scripting

Tags: shell

I was trying a sample program, to check the odd and even no's and was getting an error as below,

```
#!/bin/bash
N=10

for i in 1..N
if [$i/2 == 0]
then
        echo "even"
else
        echo "Odd"
fi
```

Error:

```
./case.sh: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `if'
./case.sh: line 5: `if [$i/2 == 0]'
```

**EDITED :**

```
#!/bin/bash
N=10

for i in 1..N
do
if(( ($i/2) == 0 ));
then
        echo "even"
else
        echo "Odd"
fi
done
```

error :

```
./case.sh: line 6: ((: (1..N/2) == 0 : syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "..N/2) == 0 ")
Odd
```

**Correct working code :**

```
#!/bin/bash
N=3

for (( i=1; i <= N; i++ ));
#for i in 1..N; // This didnt work
do
if [[ $i/2 -eq 0 ]]
#if (( i/2 == 0 ));     // This also worked
then
        echo "even"
else
        echo "Odd"
fi
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[ ]` or `[[ ]]` needs spaces between its arguments. And in your case you should use `[[ ]]` or `(( ))` as `[ ]` can't handle division along with comparison:

```
if [[ 'i / 2' -eq 0 ]]; then
if (( (i / 2) == 0 )); then
```

`for i in 1..N; do` should also be

```
for (( i = 1; i <= N; ++i )); do
```

You probably meant to have a form of brace expansion, but you can't apply a parameter name on it:

```
{1..10}  ## This will work.
{1..N}   ## This will not work.
```

Using `eval` may fix it but better go for the other form of `for` loop instead.

Comment: Thanks konsolebox. bwn why do we use two braces for "for loop" and the if statement

Comment: Is it that if there are more than one operation we use an extra brackets

Comment: @Angus To make it less complicated, just use `if (( (i / 2) == 0 )); then` as you're mainly on arithmetic anyway.

Comment: *Is it that if there are more than one operation we use an extra brackets* -> What command do you refer? And can you rephrase this? *bwn why do we use two braces for "for loop" and the if statement*

Comment: You can use single bracket `[]` when you are doing multiple operations so something like `if [ 1 -eq 1 -o 2 -ne 3 ]` can written as `if [[ 1 == 1 || 2 != 3 ]]` when using double bracket. Its just that the `[[]]` supports `||`, `&&` etc. for ease of use and some more additional functionality.

Comment: Sorry for my bad english. You have explained clearly in the last comment about my doubt. Thanks for explaining nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
#!/bin/bash
N=10

for i in $(seq 1 $N); do
if [ `expr $i % 2` -eq 0 ]
then
        echo "even"
else
        echo "Odd"
fi
done
```

`1..N` is not a valid syntax in bash(though I think you might be coming from ruby background), you can use `seq`.

Comment: does not work here either. shouldn't return 5 odds and 5 evens?

Comment: sorry my bad, fixed it now. @KarolyHorvath was correct.